# why setting ipairs as local in lua?

Tags: lua

Code:

```
local ipairs = ipairs     -- why set this ipairs as local? 

local Access = {}

function Access.find_access_tag(source,access_tags_hierarchy)
    for i,v in ipairs(access_tags_hierarchy) do
        local tag = source:get_value_by_key(v)
        if tag then
            return tag
        end
    end
    return nil
end

return Access
```

I have not seen defining ipairs as local earlier. I have tried to find it from the internet, but did not find anything useful. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: While the answers are not necessarily wrong, I want to point out that it's possible to overload `ipairs` and other library functions in different parts of the program. If the function is localized, that possibility may be reduced or eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a speedup optimization, makes sense when `ipairs()` called very frequently.

Calling global function involves searching the global environment table every time the function is called. When you copy that function into the local variable - you do not search it anymore, you just get the function from the fastest reachable location.

Comment: ipairs is only evaluated once so it makes no difference in this example

Comment: @Piglet the `Access.find_access_tag()` will do the table lookup when ipairs isn't local. So the effect depends on the frequency of calling `find_access_tag()`

Comment: ipairs is only called once... the resulting iterator is stored as a local

Comment: @Piglet The speedup isn't in calling ipairs, it's speeding up the _lookup_ of ipairs. When ipair isn't local, `find_access_tag()` will search it in the chunk's environment table. See the disassembly, there will be `GETTABUP` instruction, which does a table lookup.

Comment: @Vlad: While this answer is true, I think the other answer's warning about premature optimization and so forth is also important. Otherwise, it could give the impression that this is generally a thing people should be doing, which it most assuredly is not.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't make any difference within the provided code unless it is used in a module for example.

In Lua using local variables is faster than using globals. That is one reason why you should use local variables wherever possible.

```
local sin = math.sin
for i = 1, 1000000 do
  local x = sin(1)
end
```

is about 30% faster than

```
for i = 1, 1000000 do
  local x = math.sin(1)
end
```

but as

```
 for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end
```

is equivalent to the code:

```
do
   local f, s, var = explist
   while true do
     local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
     if var_1 == nil then break end
     var = var_1
     block
   end
 end
```

`explist` is only evaluated once so there is no performace gain in making `ipairs` local

Simple example to verify:

```
local ipairs = function(t) print("ipairs called") return ipairs(t) end
for i,v in ipairs({1,2,3}) do end
```

will only print "ipairs called" once.

But if you call `Access.find_access_tag` very often it may pay off as then you'll profit from looking up ipairs faster.

Comment: That's what happens when people try implementing optimizations they don't understand. Always write simple code, then benchmark it, and *possibly* consider what you could do to optimize it. Then benchmark again and throw out anything that doesn't actually improve performance.